# Thumbnail Image alt Attributes on Google Custom Search Engine Results Page

Tags: javascript, accessibility, google-custom-search

Running through some accessibility testing and seeing that GCSE results are displaying thumbnail images with no alt attribute. It looks like I'll have to use javascript to add this attribute, but I feel dirty in the way I've gone about doing this.

I know about firing a callback function via:

```
window.__gcse = {
  callback: myCallback
};
```

And I am able to fire a function, but I seem to have to use a setTimeout() function to ensure the images are there. I've tried using both a jQuery load() as well as on.('load', fn...) but neither seem to do the job of adding the attribute. However, using a setTimeout to give the search results some time to generate does work, but I'm afraid of this being a dirty hack.

```
// add some alt tags after google custom search has loaded results
function myCallback() {
  setTimeout(function() {jQuery('.gs-image').attr('alt','Article Thumbnail');}, 500); // empty string better than generic text
  setTimeout(function() {jQuery("img.gsc-branding-img").attr('alt','Google');}, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {jQuery(".gsc-search-button-v2").attr('alt','Search');}, 500);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking... You're from UK? I seem to remember GCSE being a high-school exam? So sounds like you've somehow gotten some HTML with exam results that you want to fix up - but nobody reading this question knows what's broken with that HTML in the first place, so can't help. Could you provide a link to an example, or copy/paste an example of some of the HTML that's broken?

Comment: Also, FWIW, if you're trying to retroactively fix up HTML coming from a 3rd party - well, it's likely going to end up being hacky regardless. Ideally you'd get back proper semantically meaningful and accessible HTML; if not, well, may just have to make do with what you got. But no way of knowing for sure without knowing what you're actually dealing with as source material in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to add alt text for accessibility for the magnifying glass search button, but so far I have not been able to add it for the Google branding image. I got this idea from https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/customsearch/Owey1Sj6oB8;context-place=forum/customsearch

(Be sure to replace 000000000000000000000:aaaaaaaaa with your own Google Custom Search Engine ID.)

```
<script>var myCallback = function() {   
document.getElementsByClassName('gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2')[0].alt = "Search Icon"; }; 
window.__gcse = {   callback: myCallback };   
  (function() {
    var cx = '000000000000000000000:aaaaaaaaa';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search linktarget="_parent"></gcse:search>
```